# Learning WebBrowser Control in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control

I want to learn the WebBrowser control component in Visual Studio. I have seen a tutorial in it and loved how we can automate different web tasks by programming in it. Such as form filling and account creation on web pages.

Can some one please name a good book targeting this special component or refer to a project related to this component.

I have searched a lot about it on the internet but could not find any solid information.

Comment: Did you really not search? Not even on MSDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't search too much: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6.aspx). Go through links in documentation, follow examples and you should get a solid understanding of the control. After that try some test application yourselves.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.. I did not knew about MSDN. But a reference book is better then a documentation as it has a teaching style. Starting from basics to advanced material while the documentation is written in a technical manner.

Comment: MSDN is a key for .NET developer. If you are not able to learn from MSDN you should change it quickly or consider changing job. You can hardly hope that there will be step-by-step book for every control.

Comment: It constantly amazes me how many developers don't know about the MSDN Library. I don't know how you can have more than a week of .NET experience without knowing about the location of all of the documentation!!!

Comment: ok  i will look into the MSDN. Actually i am confused because the link mentioned by you, only shows the class information. The methods available and info about properties. But does not show how to use them in different ways. But thanks a lot for the help

Comment: One more question. Can you please refer and good tutorial application using vB in visual studio. In which one has to develop dll files and things like that and then make them interact. It could be a windows advanced type of application.

Comment: Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms789086 or here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms789097

Comment: @user: the intention is for you to use your brain to figure out _how_ to use them.